# How to refresh UITableViewController in iphone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

```
 -(void)reloadView{
    NSLog(@"IN RELOAD VIEW ");
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
  }


  - (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIBarButtonItem * barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityIndicator];
    [self navigationItem].rightBarButtonItem = barButton;

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    [self callStudentsWebService];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    [self setTitle:@"Students"];

    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
    self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
     UIBarButtonItem *add = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add Student"        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(addStudent)];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *import =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize target:self action:@selector(addStudent)];
    NSArray* toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:add,flexible,import, nil];
    self.toolbarItems = toolbarItems;
  }
```

Above is my Code in a Class which is a subclass of `UITableViewController`.
Now my problem is when I come onto the screen First Time it get the records from web service from the method    `[self callStudentsWebService]`  . Now i have a button in `uitoolbar` in the same view which updates the list . I am calling the `reloadView` method to refresh the `List` but it calls the `numberOfRowsInSection` and `viewDidLoad` method but does not call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. But when i goto other screen and come back again it does refresh my `List` from start.

What could be the reason ?? Please help i am new in iPad Development. And i m doing all this in iPad.

Thanks alot

**EDITED**

```
@interface StudentsList : UITableViewController {
DetailViewController *detailViewController;
UIToolbar *toolbar;
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
}
```

Comment: Does `numberOfRowsInSection ` return more then zero?

Comment: Yes it does.. it it returns 5

Comment: move `[super viewDidLoad];` to the top of `- (void)viewDidLoad {`

Comment: sorry i just checked it is returing me 0

Comment: yes but what is the solution ??? Since All the Data is stored in the Array of my App delegate class.. It should not return 0... then y it is ??

Comment: Post code of method `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: Now its returning 5 the i have fixed but still it only call ViewDidLoad method and numberofRowsInSection but not calling cellForRowAtIndexPath. Please guide

Comment: If `numberOfRowsInSection` returns more then zero and `numberOfSections` return more then zero than `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should be called. Do you set delegate and data source values of table view to your controller?

Comment: yes i did selected them from my Nib file. and my Header file is something like above. I have edited my Code see there...

Comment: do I Also need to add <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> after UITableViewController in my Header File ?? PLease reply

Comment: No, you don't need to add them.

Comment: then wot could be the possible solution ??? m stucked :(

Answer (score 0):

May be your data.count is 0? If there is some data it should call cellForRowAtIndexPath after `[[self tableView] reloadData];`

Comment: Yes first it has five records then when i refresh it it still shows five records i mean i am not adding any more data into dataArray but just want it to refresh..... Any idea?? how can i do this??

Answer (score 0):

Do the refresh code in another separate method `-(void)refreshData` then call this whenever you want such as in `-viewDidLoad` or on a button tap...

Answer (score 0):

Try to call  **-(void)reloadView** from

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self reloadView];
}
```